# @query with only sort by . Without limit

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I`m trying to do select with @Query annotation with only sort by.

I searched a lot but without any luck. Currently I implemented it to work but with Pageable class that want me to set limit . Is there any other way to accomplish that without limit? Only normal select with order by

```
@Query("SELECT new com.concretepage.entity.Employee(employeeId,firstName,lastName,salary)FROM Employee")
    List<Employee> getBySalaryOrdered(Pageable pageable);
```

I`m searching for way to do it without Pageable. I want only to have sort without any limits

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting

Comment: If your method, as its name indicates, is always supposed to sort by salary, then just include the order by clause in the query.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `@Query` annotation you could use query generation based on a method definition inside the interface that extends  `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository`.

In your case, it would be:

```
List<Employee> findAllByOrderBySalaryAsc();
```

Check [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) for more.